# How can I get metricsSystem (org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem) inside the executors?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to send custom metrics from my executors, in order to do so I need to use Spark's Metric System to register the custom source I wrote.

I can get the Metric System in the driver scope by

```
SparkEnv.get.metricsSystem
```

But I can't do the same in the executor.
According to [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics) it should be available somehow.

Using Spark 1.6.1

Related to - [post](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Executor-metrics-in-spark-application-td188.html)