# How to configure executors with custom StatsD Spark metrics sink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, metrics, sink

How do I sink Spark Streaming metrics to this [StatsD sink](https://github.com/vidhyaarvind/spark-statsd/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/metrics/sink/StatsDSink.scala)  for executors?

Similar to other reported issues ([sink class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763364/metrics-system-not-recognizing-custom-source-sink-in-application-jar), [sink class in executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575418/how-can-i-get-metricssystem-org-apache-spark-metrics-metricssystem-inside-the)), I can get driver metrics, but executors throw `ClassNotFoundException` with my setup:

- [StatsD sink](https://github.com/vidhyaarvind/spark-statsd/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/metrics/sink/StatsDSink.scala) class is compiled with my Spark-Streaming app (`my.jar`)
- `spark-submit` is run with:

  - `--files ./my.jar` (to pull jar containing sink into executor)
  - `--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=my.jar"`
- Spark Conf is configured in the driver with:

  ```
  val conf = new SparkConf()

  conf.set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.statsd.class",
           "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.StatsDSink")
      .set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.statsd.host", conf.get("host"))
      .set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.statsd.port", "8125")
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Looks you hit the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18115. I hit it too and googled your question :(

Answer (score 1):

Copy your jar files to the $SPARK_HOME/jars folder.

Comment: Thanks. Succeed on YARN `spark-submit` job. But could you explain why? Why is not enough run with parameters-`--files` or `extraClassPath`?